# Does any functional programming language have significant libraries for natural language processing?

Tags: functional-programming, nlp

I am doing natural language processing using NLTK for Python.

I find myself doing my programming more in the functional style, and am thinking about switching to a functional language. However, I need a good NLP library, at least comparable to NLTK.

Do you know a functional programming language which has good NLP libraries? I discovered that there is some NLP activity in the Haskell community, but it seems still in it's infancy compared to NLTK.

Comment: Have you looked at python's `functools` module? If you can't find a good pure functional alternative, it should help with writing functional-style code for the nltk.

Comment: Do you genuinely not enjoy programming in a functional style in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala and Clojure

Both run on the JVM, so you can take advantage of all the java nlp and machine learning libraries (Stanford Parser, Lingpipe, Mallet, etc). Java blows everything except Python away in terms of NLP libraries except python, but is a bit less user friendly. To use the Stanford Parser programmatically can be a bit of the pain in the ass; I had to write my own wrapper for it.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dakrone/clojure-opennlp
It is a clojure wrapper for Apache OpenNLP.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Linguistics